# CosmosDb and RU's for the same query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a CosmosDB collection with id field and a partition key ManagerName.
When I run two queries.

```
SELECT * FROM c
where c.id = '76e24380-71cb-45d5-807a-ce2374f57624' and c.ManagerName ='Darin Jast2'

SELECT * FROM c
where c.id = '76e24380-71cb-45d5-807a-ce2374f57624'
```

in data explorer the RU's result is sort of strange. For the first query I get 3.070 RUs and the second I get 2.9 RUs. Almost every time I run the two queries?
That is strange to me because from what I read when you have a partition id in the where clause the query will run on a single partition.

The stranger thing is that when I run a

```
SELECT * FROM c
where c.ManagerName ='Darin Jast2'
```

I get 2.9 in fact any field I get the same number. It seams to be related to the number of where conditions instead of having or not having partitions? 
Can someone explain to me what is going on here and why am I getting the results. Dose this have something to do with indexing? Size of the collection? Number of partitions?
All the resources I found on CosmosDb say you should include the partition key in your query and if you can do single partition queries.

Comment: Let us know if you figure this out